# Where can i find spring-dojo.js for dojo Version 1.7.2?

Tags: javascript, dojo

i want to update dojo to 1.7.2.
Can someone tell me where i can find the related spring-dojo.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: there is no support for Dojo 1.7 in Spring.

Long answer: other people have tried to upgrade Dojo to the latest version while using Spring Javascript, and they gave up after a couple of days. See this blog entry:
http://www.rimple.com/tech/2012/3/1/quizzo-its-thursday-must-go-into-the-dojo-and-meditate.html

Answer (score 1):

Spring-Js is a dead project. Even in Jan 2014 they're still bundling the 2010 version of Dojo as it looks like either no one wants to upgrade it, or no one is maintaining it any longer. Last Github [update was 4 years ago](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow/tree/master/spring-js-resources).

Further, Dojo has made breaking changes since 1.5.0 which will cause various SpringJs functions to fail.

I detailed my experience on this [Spring Forums post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo/92172-change-version-of-dojo-in-my-project).